# Dijkstra's algorithm while moving through a maze

Tags: python, dijkstra, robotics

Trying to navigate a maze using Dijkstra's algorithm but I am getting errors that i don't know how to fix. after trying to fix said error it threw up an error first saying put ".any()" at the end of an if statement-
`if Maze[tuple(currentCoords)] == "_".any():`

after I did this it threw up another error which is-

```
    if Maze[tuple(currentCoords)] == "_".any():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'any'
```

Now I don't really know what to do the code should be moving through the maze while also checking the next available square.

This is my code

```
import time
import numpy as np

# The 7 by 7 grid provided. X is the starting square,
# _ represents a square, Y is the finishing square
# and Z is an obstacle.
Maze = np.array([
    "X", "_", "_", "_", "_", "Z", "_",
    "_", "Z", "Z", "Z", "_", "_", "_",
    "_", "Z", "_", "_", "_", "_", "Z",
    "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_",
    "_", "_", "Z", "_", "Z", "Z", "_",
    "_", "_", "Z", "_", "Z", "_", "_",
    "_", "_", "Z", "_", "_", "_", "Y"
])

# Reshape the 1D array into a 2D 7x7 grid
Maze = Maze.reshape((7, 7))

CurrentValue = "Y"
i = 0

# If not on the starting square, the robot will move to
# a new square and check if it is an obstacle or a new 
# square.

def check_next_coordinates(X, Y):
    if 0 <= X < 7 and 0 <= Y < 7:
        return Maze[X, Y] != "Z"
    return False

while CurrentValue != "X":
    currentCoords = np.argwhere(Maze == CurrentValue)
    print("Current Coordinates:", currentCoords[-1])
    time.sleep (1)
    print(Maze)

    # If the new square is an empty space, mark it as the current value + 1.
    print(Maze[tuple(currentCoords[-1])])
    if Maze[tuple(currentCoords)] == "_".any():

        Maze[tuple(currentCoords[-1])] = str(int(CurrentValue) + 1)
    elif Maze[tuple(currentCoords[-1])] == "X":
        print("Maze:", Maze)
        CurrentValue = "X"

    X = currentCoords[-1]
    Y = currentCoords[-7]

    # Check the left space
    left_x, left_y = X, Y - 1
    if check_next_coordinates(left_x, left_y):
        if Maze[left_x, left_y] == "_":
            Maze[left_x, left_y] = str(int(CurrentValue) + 1)
        elif Maze[left_x, left_y] == "X":
            print("Left space is available")
            CurrentValue = "X"

    # Check the above space
    above_X, above_Y = X - 1, Y
    if check_next_coordinates(above_X, above_Y):
        if Maze[above_X, above_Y] == "_":
            Maze[above_X, above_Y] = str(int(CurrentValue) + 1)
        elif Maze[above_X, above_Y] == "X":
            print("Space above is available")
            CurrentValue = "X"

    print (Maze)
```

Is there anything I need to add to the code or change as I don't really know what I am doing because I am fairly new to coding.
All help appreciated thank you.

Comment: The first error you got is probably going to be much more helpful...

Comment: You say "I am getting errors that i don't know how to fix. after trying to fix said error it threw up an error first saying put ".any()" at the end of an if statement". What told you to put `.any()` there? Whatever did, you either misinterpreted or it is just plain wrong. Strings don't have a `.any()` method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.